# Найти и исправить все риснунки с размером больше 100% в MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Как используя VBA найти в документе все рисунки для которых размер выставлен больше 100% относительно исходного, и установить его равным 100% для таких рисунков?

[image: Пример]

Пробовал записать макрос чтобы понять как это сделать, но операция установки масштаба не записывается :(

Во вложении пример документа с двумя рисунками. Второй рисунок в нем как раз с масштабом большим, чем 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
For Each Shape In Doc.Shapes
  Dim Figure As Shape
  Set Figure = Shape
  ' Изображение содержит подпись?
  If Figure.Type = msoAutoShape And Figure.TextFrame.HasText Then
    With Figure.TextFrame.TextRange
      ' Количество абзацев равно 2? (изображение и подпись)
      If .Paragraphs.Count = 2 Then
        If .InlineShapes.Count = 1 Then
          Dim picture As InlineShape
          Set picture = .InlineShapes(1)
          ' Если масштаб картинки больше чем 100%, ставим его равным 100%
          If picture.ScaleWidth > 100 Then
            picture.ScaleWidth = 100
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End With
  End If
Next
```